# In an aircraft, should I connect flanges of wing spars' to the fuselage, or webs of wing spars' to the fuselage?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aircraft-design

I am actually trying to understand which option is going to be a more relaible for the wing-fuselage attachment. Should I choose a connection between the flanges of the spars within the wing to the internal structure of the fuselage, or I should go with the attachment of webs of the spars within wing to the fuselage? What most of the aircrafts opt for, and does it depend on what aircraft category it belongs to (like commercial/fighter/cargo etc).

If any answers are provided, it would be appreciated to back it up with reasons.

*(Does aircrafts also connect the wing skin to the fuselage skin? If yes, then what kind of aircrafts do that and why).*

Comment: Do you understand what the web is supposed to do? And what the spar is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes. spar webs carry the shear loads while spar flanges carry the bending loads. But I saw some aircraft designs where connections were made between the spar webs and fuselage, while some had connections with spar flanges and fuselage. So I don't know why are they going for different options.

Comment: You are asking whether the fuselage should mount to the spar or the shear web right?

Comment: I just know what kind of loads each carry. But from the connection point of view, I don't know which one makes sense and why.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you're getting at. The spar is what you need to connect to since that is supposed to be what carries the bending load, but sometimes you just can't because it's too thin. Nowhere to grab onto. In cases like that , the web is reinforced near the root to transmit forces to the spar. Like a foam wing with thin carbon spar caps. And yes, stressed skin designs exist.

Comment: So why are spars the first priority over webs? Because they just transmit the bending loads, then what would happen to the shear load (assuming I don't have any web to fuselage connection).

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand what a shear web is for or what a shear load is. Read up model airplane stuff. It's easier to digest. Shear webs just keep the top and bottom spars apart and stops the from sliding relative to each other when bent. That's it. https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showatt.php?attachmentid=9968357&d=1492562275

Comment: @DKNguyen, can you also share a link of this complete course by Mark Drela?

Comment: That article isn't from a course as far as I know. It's a two-part article from a magazine. But he has stuff everywhere.

Comment: @DKNguyen, can you tell briefly that why would the skins of the wing couldn't carry any bending loads (like axial compression or tension)? I mean mostly we assume that its the sparcaps which carry the bending load, but why can't the skin carry any although they are located as far away from the neutral axis of the cross section as the sparcaps.

Comment: Please read up on composite wings, stressed skin design, and composite fibers (or even wood grain) that run span wise versus those that run chordwise, or those on a  +/-45 degree bias. Each is intended to handle the forces you are talking about. You should investigate the directions the forces are in an i-beam and the direction of torsion forces in a twisted tube. Sounds like you jumped over some basic mechanics directly to wings.

Comment: I have read about all of these but it has been quite a time. I was not able to recall the reasoning behind the queries I asked here. I thought maybe someone could help me recall. Anyways, I guess now its time to go back in past and recall these myself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your asking about lightweight airplanes like Cessna 172 or Cherokee Warrior etc. The big airplanes structure is hardly reducible to members as simple as spar or its web and flange.

Cessna 150 and 172, 180, and some others have two pipe stub outs that attach to the fasteners connected to the continued pipe built in the fuselage on top of the cockpit.

They are only compression, tension member of a truss whose diagonal strut is attached mid-wing to the landing gear.

Cherokee has its spar continue under the fuselage and attached to special brackets on the two sides with flanges and web both connected.

Every design has been calculated and tested not just for bending moment and shear but any complex combination of twist and torque and vibration and unsymmetrical loading.

As for the skin, I don't know about the new composite carbon fiber skins but the classic aluminum, that I repaired myself (as an emergency, I am a PPL pilot), is mostly simple sheets of aluminum riveted or screwed to the frame and they are designed to have seams at convenient places so as not creat parasite stresses due to wind or vibration. The Cessna is a monocoque structure meaning the skin is the structure. Below is a figure of a Cessna 172.

.

[image: Cessna 172]